# VBA Can't return value from cell (Visio)

Tags: vba, visio

I have a visio document with shapes and relevant shape data. Im attempting to pull data from these shapes.
A few of the shape data fields are formulas (which display the correct value in Visio) however when getting those values I'm not sure how to return the value as a string.

Here is the call:

```
avarFormulaArray(iCell) = 
shp.CellsSRC(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, iRow, 
Visio.VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue).FormulaU
```

These easy answer is use `.Result` instead of `.FormulaU` however that won't work as it's not of the correct type (FormulaArray) which must be a formula. Not sure how to get around this at the moment.
Any help is appreciated.

**Solution using @JonFournier 's advice**

```
"""" & shp.CellsSRC(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, iRow, Visio.VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue).ResultStr(Visio.VisUnitCodes.visNoCast) & """"
```

The following snippet ensures no matter what is in the shape sheet cell the resulting value/string is returned.
`.ResultStr(Visio.VisUnitCodes.visNoCast)`

The addition of the quotes appended to the beginning and end give me the result (value/string) as if it was returned using my original `.FormulaU' but will compute the formulas and return the values rather than the actual formula.

The use of `.ResultU` or `.Result` will return 0 for everything that isn't a value thus strings wont work as they are returned as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .Result(visUnitCode) or .ResultIU() to get the value from a cell.

Comment: Thank you much John, this worked perfectly!!!  Just out of curiosity, what resources do you use for VB/VBA/VBscript. I'm very new and have had trouble finding good resources especially those that refer to VBA in Visio. I am aware of Visio guy which has really bene the only comprehensive resource other than micorosoft., but microsoft lacks any 'community/ commentary'  like what we find on stackoverflow etc...Thanks Again!

Comment: Primarily I use the VBA macro recorder in Visio, which is by far the easiest way to learn all these things.  The next best is to keep searching stack overflow and asking questions when you can't find the answer.  The MSDN documentation for Visio Automation is pretty poor, but it at least sometimes tells you something useful.  You might want to get the Visio Developer's Survival Guide, which can be helpful.  I don't know if it's up to date, but the 2003 version holds up still.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Visio haven't **.Value** !It have **.Result** 
What kind of data type you can use in this field ?

Comment: thanks I wasn't aware .Value is not applicable.  I ended up using the following:[avarFormulaArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/subscriptions/ms427197.aspx)   According to the spec it grabs the formula of the cell. I may be stuck with my design as is. There's no context to find the value later on in my macro. I've worked around this problem with some compromises.

Answer (score 0):

Literature about Visio VBA:

> [Developing Microsoft Visio Solutions (Pro-Documentation)](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.268.1.1/1/)
>   [Chapter No.2 "Understanding the Microsoft Visio Object Model](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/0141-chapter-2-understanding-the-microsoft-visio-object%20.pdf?utm_source=packtpub&utm_medium=free&utm_campaign=pdf) from book [Microsoft Visio 2010 Business Process Diagramming and Validation](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/microsoft-visio-2010-business-process-diagramming-and-validation) by [David John Parker](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/21090?fullName=David%20John%20Parker)
>   [Chapter No. 3 Understanding the ShapeSheet™](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781782178002_Chapter-03.pdf?utm_source=packtpub&utm_medium=free&utm_campaign=pdf) from book [Microsoft Visio 2013 Business Process Diagramming and Validation](http://www.packtpub.com/microsoft-visio-2013-business-process-diagramming-and-validation) by David John Parker

Video:

> [Visio, a flyby for developers (Part 2)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Office-Dev/Visio-a-flyby-for-developers-Part-2) by [John Goldsmith](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/4020443?fullName=John%20%20Goldsmith) / [John Goldsmith on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683606/johngoldsmith)